# Working with MVC, I want to retrieve a value from my cshtml view and store it in my SignalR hub

Tags: signalr, postback

I am currently designing a game and need to retrieve a value from my view and send it to my SingalR hub.

I want to store the value retrieved from my view in a global variable in my hub.

Example as below:

**View**

```
<html>
    Viewbag.a=1 //the value i want to send to the hub
<html>
```

**Hub**

```
int a; //global variable in hub

public void retrieve(int num) //my method to store value
{
    a=num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic, assuming you have connected to your hub. I think the code speaks for itself:

```
<script>
    var num = @ViewBag.a;

    //connect to hub here

    proxy.server.retrieve(num);
</script>
```